# Mapping Django URLs in JQuery append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am appending an anchor tag dynamically after an AJAX call completes, but I'm not able to set the `href` attribute of it as a Django URL. Here's my code:

```
$maincontent.append("<a id='resultslink'>Get results here</a>");
$('#resultslink').attr('href', "{% url 'results' %}");
```

Django gives the following error -

```
The current path, InitialWebApp/hdfs/{%, didn't match any of these.
```

Apparently, Django thinks `{%` is the `href` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the url using the `url` template tag requires that the template be rendered again which doesn't happen after your AJAX call.

You can either hardcode the url or have the resolved url returned as part of the payload from the server for each AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. I hardcoded the anchor tag in the HTML template.